# CasperJS viewport & viewportSize not resizing browser

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, viewport, casperjs

Is anyone having any issues lately with the CasperJS or PhantomJS `viewport` or `viewportSize`?

I've tried using

```
page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};
casper.start()
      .viewport(800, 600);
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1290, height: 1024};
```

No matter where I put them in the code the browser size still stays the default 300, 400.

```
/*jshint strict:false*/
/*global CasperError, console, phantom, require*/

var links = [];
var casper = require("casper").create();
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;


function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("h3.r a");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        try {
            // google handles redirects hrefs to some script of theirs
            return (/url\?q=(.*)&sa=U/).exec(e.getAttribute("href"))[1];
        } catch (err) {
            return e.getAttribute("href");
        }
    });
}

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 950};

casper.start("http://google.fr/", function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.viewport(900, 800);
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: "casperjs" }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    // now search for 'phantomjs' by fillin the form again
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: "phantomjs" }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
});


console.log("Height==> " + h);
console.log("Width==> " + w);


casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + " links found:");
    this.echo(" - " + links.join("\n - "));
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: At least the middle one will work. Please provide a complete and minimal script that reproduces your problem.

Comment: That's not really minimal and depends on a lot of stuff. Try a minimal test script. It's only a guess: It may be a problem with using multiple `start()` and `run()` calls in a nested fashion: calling `next()` will `start()` a new run. There should only be one `start()`-`run()` pair per `casper.test.begin()`.

Comment: Minimal code now, the var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight; are still returning the default 300, 400

Comment: Now, there are multiple problems with your code. 1. `window.innerWidth` must be retrieved from the page context, not outside. 2. CasperJS is asynchronous by nature. When you're printing `w` and `h`, you're printing values that you set before you even set anything else. ... Just take a screenshot with `casper.capture()` and see if the horizontal dimension matches your setting.